# NODEJS updated variable. Why am I not receiving the updated variable1 value

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to change the COMPANYDATA variable1 to query a specific SCHEMA based on a user's company_data field.

file1.js

```
const {changeVariable, variable1 } = require('../lib/workshopdata');

customers.get('/', isLoggedIn, async(req, res) =\> {
const { ID } = req.params;

await changeVariable(req.user.company_data);

COMPANYDATA = await variable1;

console.log("The company data to use should be this new value =  "+variable1);

try {
    const customer = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM '+COMPANYDATA+'.customers order by name',  [ID]);  
    res.render('customers/customerlist', {customer: customer});
}catch{
    res.redirect("/newuser.html");
}

});
```

file2.js

```
const express = require('express');
const pool = require('../database');

let variable1 = 'DEFAULT COMPANY';

async function changeVariable(newValue) {
try {
    console.log("Current value of variable1:", variable1);
    console.log("THE REQUESTED PARAMETER IS : ", newValue);

// Use parameterized query to prevent SQL injection
const result = await pool.query("SELECT company_data FROM workshops.users WHERE company_data =     ?", [newValue]);

// Assuming the query returns a single row, you can access the value as follows
if (result.length > 0) {
  variable1 = result[0].company_data;
  console.log("Variable1 has changed to:", variable1);
  return(variable1);
} else {
  console.log("No matching data found in the database.");
}

} catch (error) {
console.error("Error in Company:", error);
throw error; // Rethrow the error for handling in the calling 
function or middleware
}
}

module.exports = { changeVariable, variable1 };
```

I am trying to change the COMPANYDATA variable1 to query a specific SCHEMA based on a user's company_data field.

Comment: `file1.js` doesn't even import `variable1` (or `changeVariable`, for that matter). Also `variable1` is never set to a promise so `await variable1` is useless. It would work if you would export both the variable and the function from `file2.js` and import them in `file1.js`, but **only in case of ES modules** (where the imported `variable1` would be a live binding). You seem to be using CommonJS, so it can't work this way anyway because `variable1` would be _copied_ on importing it, so any changes wouldn't affect the copy. You could make it work by exporting a function `getVariable1()` though.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add the import line at the top   i.e. const {changeVariable, variable1 } = require('../lib/workshopdata');

Comment: I will update the question

Comment: Please see the second half of my comment of why it can't work this way.

Comment: Thank you CherryDT I managed to get this fixed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

make sure you have import variable right way.